# Easiest Way to Parse Data from a Webpage to XML

Tags: html, xml

I need to create a daily process which pulls market data from a website http://www.apxendex.com/index.php?id=137.

I had originally created an excel+VBA sheet which added the data to an xml file and this worked fine. However, the machine which I will be putting the code on doesn't have excel so all my work was pointless (stupid I know).

I'm not looking for someone to write anything for me, but some general tips on where to start, what language to go for etc. would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How did you get your information from the website?
There is a DataCapture API for that site. You can find the manual on  [this site (you have to login to see the manual).](http://www.apxendex.com/index.php?id=56)  
 I guess it would be the easiest way to go the recommended way.